# MS Excel: Multiple condition based matrix search

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have following scenario to fetch cost against number of links (of a specific type) deployed by a Vendor. I have tried VLookup + Index-Match but it doesn't behave as I want it to be. Only Index-Match works for single matrix but it does't get values WRT media type i.e: Fiber Optics, DSL or DRS.

**Table 1**:  This table has number of links and will output amount of each vendor.

e.g. we have **2** links of "100Mbps" "Fiber Optic" provided by "Vendor 1".
We have **18** links of "1Mbps" "DSL" provided by "Vendor 3"

[image]

**Table 2**:  This table contains price of each link WRT vendor.

e.g: "Vendor 1" charges **400** for "100Mbps" "Fiber Optic" link.
"Vendor 3" charges **80** for "512Kbps" "DRS" link.

[image: Charges of Vendor per link]

**Requirement**: I need **Amount** in Table-1 to be calculated with respect to price of relevant vendor for specific media and bandwidth.
e.g. **Amount** for 2 links of "100Mbps" "Fiber Optics", provided by "Vendor 1" would be:: 400 X 2 = 800.

For me Index-Match works fine for "Vendor X Bandwidth" but am unable to include "Media" in the selection criteria.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this [image]

Let me know if you have questions, formula is an array formula... CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER

```
=G4*INDEX($C$11:$E$22,MATCH($B4,IF($A$11:$A$22=$A4,$B$11:$B$22),0),MATCH(H$2,$C$10:$E$10,0))
```

Drag down in each of the amount columns and you're golden. I simplified the top array for timesake, but it uses INDEX + MATCH with two criteria. Notice I did not use merge, you can't in this case unless you want extra work and to edit each formula.

If you don't like this, hide the column.

Comment: Edited image to include formula with colored legend

Comment: Thanks!! I didn't had idea to use if in this situation. Working perfectly fine.